# Bad tesseract screenshots recognition results

Tags: python, windows, ocr, screen-scraping

I am experimenting with PyTesseract recognition of text captured from other programs. Results are surprisingly bad. I thought this is simple problem given that scanned documents recognition was pretty good more than 20 years ago.

For example for [image] I am getting

```
"win32¢gui.EnumWindows(enum_cb, toplist)

winInfos = [(hwnd, title) for hwnd, title in winlist if
print("™sd process(es) found" % Len(winInfos))

wininfo = winInfos[@]

hwnd = wininfo[@]

# w2 = win32gui.Findwindow(None, “"Chrome")

for i in range(10):

 
eel eee"
```

Even worser without zooming and different background and text colors.

I don't need perfect solution (this is rather experimental project), but need at least something adequate. I am not limited much with ways how to implement/fix this. Only limited with Windows and Python is also very desirable. I know Python more or less and experienced in programming in whole, but newbie in text recognition.

Tesseract was the first library I tried. I read it is one of the best. I already know it likes big fonts (although for screenshots where all identical symbols always looks identically I thought 8 pixels height is pretty enough). And see zooming and making all backgrounds and text colors equal help, but not enough. I am going to recognize contents of tables with different text color and maybe backgrounds so it would be desirable not to stumble over such things.

The ways of solving I see:

- to increase fonts in the source program to get "true" higher resolution (not sure this will help enough),
- to train Tesseract on my fonts (quick search revealed this is very boring - instructions with 20 steps or with Python scripts I don't have),
- to try other libraries.

What could you recommend?

Thanks

Comment: It highly depends on font and size, for my command line `tesseract -l eng image.png stdout` outputs `0` as `@`, `win32` as `win3Z`, and so on.

Comment: @BladeMight, yes, I see. Results are not only bad, they are not stable. What would you recommend for example for the font, used above?

Comment: Maybe that is the best possible result at this time, since no one been adding support for code-screenshots recognition in tesseract, e.g. rules that can *actually* think what you need. At least you should try [improve quality](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality), if that won't work then you should train tesseract...

Comment: You should probably convert the image to greyscale and then to binary if you have problems with colors.

Comment: @DonQuiKong, no, this didn't help noticeably

Comment: I used Tesseract for some time to read documents in the Edsgar Dijkstra's archive. As long as it were English words the results were near 95%. When Dijkstra started writing an Algol program, the results were nearly a disaster. The correctness of the transcription depends much on the word being a correct word. Training is a hard job, but necessary in this case.

Comment: I used PyTesseract on 300dpi greyscale scans of German texts and the results were equally disappointing, despite using `lang="deu"`. This being normal text, at least I could somewhat correct them with a spellchecker.